# Correct Syntax of Element binding in XML view with JSON model

Tags: sapui5

Trying to get right syntax for context binding in XML view. I have a JSON model and set the model to view with name "company" inside controller. When I use absolute path, it works but when I use relative path, it doesn't. It seems, view is unable to access the model in second case.

### My Code

```xml
<Text text ="{company>/data/name}" width="200px"/>
<Input binding="{company>/data}" value ="{name}" width="200px"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When binding a property, you also have to provide the name of the model. Otherwise the "nameless" default model is assumed. But since all your data is in the `company` model you have to explicitly state that name for your value.

```
<Input binding="{company>/data}" value="{company>name}" width="200px"/>
```

Comment: that works! Thank you very much.  My expectation was, I do not need to mention the model name again , because I already did that in "binding".

Comment: @SQL_NOVICE Glad to hear it worked :) Please [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to let others know that this issue is resolved now.

Comment: @SQL_NOVICE the beauty of it is that you can use multiple models this way. For example you can do `value="{i18n>label.companyName} {company>name}"` and  combine a translated value of your i18n file with the value of your json model. The binding just makes it easier to access a specific entry of your model.